# Error when installing scarpy on 10.12

Tags: python, scrapy, spyder

Following the instruction but still have those problems.

> RjkdeMacBook-Pro:~ kk-macbookair$ scrapy
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 9, in 
>           load_entry_point('Scrapy==1.4.0', 'console_scripts', 'scrapy')()
>         File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 565, in load_entry_point
>           return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
>         File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2697, in load_entry_point
>           return ep.load()
>         File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2370, in load
>           return self.resolve()
>         File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2376, in resolve
>           module = **import**(self.module_name, fromlist=['**name**'], level=0)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 9, in 
>           from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 7, in 
>           from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/reactor.py", line 38, in 
>           from twisted.internet import default
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/default.py", line 56, in 
>           install = _getInstallFunction(platform)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/default.py", line 50, in _getInstallFunction
>           from twisted.internet.selectreactor import install
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/selectreactor.py", line 18, in 
>           from twisted.internet import posixbase
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 18, in 
>           from twisted.internet import error, udp, tcp
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 28, in 
>           from twisted.internet._newtls import (
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_newtls.py", line 21, in 
>           from twisted.protocols.tls import TLSMemoryBIOFactory, TLSMemoryBIOProtocol
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 63, in 
>           from twisted.internet._sslverify import _setAcceptableProtocols
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 38, in 
>           TLSVersion.TLSv1_1: SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1_1,
>       AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OP_NO_TLSv1_1'
>       RjkdeMacBook-Pro:~ kk-macbookair$

Comment: What is `10.12`?

Comment: I think OSX version

Comment: Can you try running: 
`pip install --upgrade scrapy` 
`pip install --upgrade twisted` 
`pip install --upgrade pyopenssl`